# Installing wai-extra on Windows

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a problem installing `wai-extra`. It is required by `servant-server` which I'm using. I added `servant-server` to dependencies of my project and when i run `cabal build` I get the following error message during the installation of `wai-extra`:

```
Preprocessing library for wai-extra-3.1.9..
Building library for wai-extra-3.1.9..
[ 1 of 36] Compiling Network.Wai.EventSource.EventStream ( Network\Wai\EventSource\EventStream.hs, dist\build\Network\Wai\EventSource\EventStream.o )
[ 2 of 36] Compiling Network.Wai.EventSource ( Network\Wai\EventSource.hs, dist\build\Network\Wai\EventSource.o )
[ 3 of 36] Compiling Network.Wai.Handler.CGI ( Network\Wai\Handler\CGI.hs, dist\build\Network\Wai\Handler\CGI.o )

Network\Wai\Handler\CGI.hs:58:35: error:
    Not in scope: `System.IO.stdin'
    No module named `System.IO' is imported.
   |
58 |     let input = requestBodyHandle System.IO.stdin
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Network\Wai\Handler\CGI.hs:59:25: error:
    Not in scope: `System.IO.stdout'
    No module named `System.IO' is imported.
   |
59 |         output = B.hPut System.IO.stdout
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Network\Wai\Handler\CGI.hs:69:35: error:
    Not in scope: `System.IO.stdin'
    No module named `System.IO' is imported.
   |
69 |     let input = requestBodyHandle System.IO.stdin
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Network\Wai\Handler\CGI.hs:70:25: error:
    Not in scope: `System.IO.stdout'
    No module named `System.IO' is imported.
   |
70 |         output = B.hPut System.IO.stdout
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Network\Wai\Handler\CGI.hs:183:22: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `Handle'
    |
183 | requestBodyHandle :: Handle -> Int -> IO (IO B.ByteString)
    |                      ^^^^^^
cabal.exe: Failed to build wai-extra-3.1.9
```

My OS is Windows 10, cabal version is 3.6.2.0, ghc version is 9.0.1

Comment: It looks like you've run into [this bug](https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/issues/879).  It may be enough to add a specific dependency on `wai-extra ==3.1.10`, but I'm not too familiar with building without `stack`.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr this turned out to be the case